# To show/hide file upload control based on value of hiddenfield in repeater

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, repeater, hidden-field

I have one repeater control on ASP.Net page. It has one check box, label, file upload control and 3 hiddenfields. I want to hide/show a file upload control based on value of one of the hidden fields.

Here is code snippet for ItemDataBound Event of repeater.

```
protected void rptChecks_ItemDataBound (object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    HiddenField hdID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnCheckID");
    HiddenField hdDocOpt = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnDocOption");
    FileUpload fileCheck = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fileDocument");

    if ( Convert.ToInt32(hdDocOpt.Value) == 0 || Convert.ToInt32(hdDocOpt.Value) == 1)
            fileCheck.Visible = true;
        else
            fileCheck.Visible = false;
}
```

Here is a markup code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChecks" runat="server" 
                onitemdatabound="rptChecks_ItemDataBound">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                &nbsp;
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                &nbsp;
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                &nbsp;
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCheck" runat="server" Text="<%#Bind('Name') %>"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-left: 10px">
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnDocOption" runat="server" Value="<%#Bind('DocumentOption') %>" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCheckID" runat="server" Value="<%#Bind('ID') %>" />
                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fileDocument" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

How can I do this?

Error: **error occurred as Object reference not set to an instance of an object at if-condition**.

Comment: Your code looks good. What is the issue you are having?

Comment: error occurred as Object reference not set to an instance of an object at if-condition.

Comment: Can you post your markup with the repeater?

Comment: I have edited my post. Kindly go through the markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is when you try to find the controls in HeaderTemplate and use the value, in this case value is always null. We should find the controls in ItemTemplate like below:

```
protected void rptChecks_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        HiddenField hdID = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnCheckID");

        HiddenField hdDocOpt = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnDocOption");

        FileUpload fileCheck = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("fileDocument");

        if (Convert.ToInt32(hdDocOpt.Value) == 0 || Convert.ToInt32(hdDocOpt.Value) == 1)
            fileCheck.Visible = true;
        else
            fileCheck.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got that. Thank You.